# How to install lib32-libpulse? `apt-get lib32-libpulse` gives "invalid operation"

Tags: apt, skype

I have a problem with Skype. So I found that the solution to it is to install `lib32-libpulse-4.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar` library.

I found that I should install `ia32-libs`. So I installed it without any problems.

Then I try to type : `apt-get lib32-libpulse`

and I get `E: Invalid operation lib32-libpulse`

Why? What should I do to solve this?

Comment: I may be mistaken but: `apt-get` is the command-line tool for handling packages, I'm pretty sure you only need it for installing and upgrading packages, in your case you seem to have already done that. Have you tried running skype since? (after a reboot)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as the error tells you `lib32-libpulse` is not a valid operation.

That is because the correct syntax is `apt-get install lib32-libpulse` - The `install` keyword tells `apt` what to do - in this case, install.

However, as you say you already installed lib32-libpulse - Your problem should already have been resolved. You do not need to "run" a `lib`, in most cases, as these are just libraries - a bundle of data for use with other programs, no actual programs in and of themselves.

(For future reference: `man <program>` usually tells you precisely what you're doing wrong, particularly when the error message indicates a meta-problem - syntax error, or similar)